# How to connect to AWS Chime API?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to connect to AWS Chime API.

I create a dedicated user and provided it with the necessary policy (All Control) on Chime:

```
arn:aws:iam::accountid:policy/Chime
```

According to this article: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/chime/latest/dg/sdk-available-regions.html controlling Chime is not available on all the regions and I'm in a region which doesn't allow to control Chime.

So in my requests, I'm using the region **us-east-1** which is, according to article, allowed to control Chime.

But for any request I'm getting the error:

```
{"Code":"Unauthorized","Message":"User is not authorized","RequestId":null,"Resource":null}
```

What should I check further?

Answer (score 0):

new AWS.Chime({ region: REGION });
The region should be only chime allowed regions and other regions are not allowed